# Passing a variable to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable declared:

```
var recent;
```

And I wrote a function which needs the variable passed into it. However, I believe what is happening is the variable is being passed as a string. The var is represented by `thisVar`:

```
function detachVariable(thisDiv, thisVar, fileName) {

    //Check if this section is visible:
    if($(thisDiv + " li").length > 0) {
        $(thisDiv).prepend(thisVar);
    } else {

        //If variable does not have content stored, store it:
        if(thisVar === undefined) {

            $("#site-nav li a").parents().removeClass("nav-active");
            $(this).addClass("nav-active");
            $(thisDiv + " ul.top-level").load('assets/includes/' + thisFile, function () {
                $(this).show().siblings().hide();
                ajaxAudioController();
            });

            //If variable has content, show it:
        } else {
            $("#site-nav li a").parents().removeClass("nav-active");
            $(this).addClass("nav-active");
            $(thisDiv).prepend(thisVar);
        }
    }

}
```

My click function:

```
$("#site-nav .nav1").on("click", function (event) {
    detachVariable("#recent", "recent", "recent.php");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there a way I can pass my variable into the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly.. all you have to do is remove the quotes around `recent`.. see below,

```
detachVariable("#recent", recent, "recent.php"); //removed quotes
```

Comment: With that I get an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: thisFile is not defined"

Comment: `thisFile` in line `$(thisDiv + " ul.top-level").load('assets/includes/' + thisFile, function () {` is not defined inside the function `detachVariable`

Answer (score 1):

Just omit the quotes around the second parameter. With them, you are indeed passing a string literal instead of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Javascript have a global scope. So you can literally just use `recent == whatever` instead of trying to pass it as a parameter.